# WCF enum - any way to transfer both valid enum values AND numbers

Tags: .net, wcf, enums

Suppose you have:

```
 public enum Priority : short
        {

            Low = 100
            Normal = 200,
            High = 300
        }
```

I'd like to call WCF service with following call

```
myWCF.call(Priority.Low);
myWCF.call(Priority.High);
myWCF.call(105);
```

Is that possible to do without rewriting half of WCF stack? I'd prefer as solution where all WCF config settings  would be done to enum type.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you asking if you can have an overloaded method in WCF?  I'm not sure why you think you would need to rewrite the WCF stack.  I think you'd be surprised how extensible WCF is.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, sure - you could add a second property to your data contract which reflects the int-value of the enum:

```
[DataContract]
public class YourData
{
   [DataMember]
   public Priority MyPriority { get; set; }

   [DataMember]
   public int MyPriorityAsInt 
   {  
      get { return (int)MyPriority; }
      set { ; }
   }
}
```

I would think this should work - and `MyPriorityAsInt` should always accurately reflect the value stored in `MyPriority`. If you want to, you could even create the setter method for `MyPriorityAsInt` to set the value of `MyPriority` as needed.